# How to get rid of Dirac deltas in a phase space integration of one final particle procecess?

Tags: scattering-cross-section

I was trying to compute a cross section of a process $AB\to{}C$ using formula (4.79) from Peskin

$d\sigma=\frac{1}{2E_A2E_B|v_A-v_B|}\frac{d^3p}{2E(2\pi)^3}|M|^2\delta^4(p_A+p_B-p) $

The problem is I only have a integration over three variables and four deltas, so the final result will have a delta. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The time components of the various momenta are related to the spatial components via the mass-shell condition. The operation
$$\int d^3p$$
causes $\vec p$ to be set equal to $\vec p_A+\vec p_B$.

Comment: I know that. But that gives me a cross section with a delta, which is a problem. I wanna get rid of the last remainning delta

Comment: How so? Schematically, you are integrating $\delta^4(p^\mu)=\delta(E)\delta^3(\vec p)$ where $E=\sqrt{m^2+\vec p^2}$. The $\vec p$ integral takes care of all four deltas.

Comment: No it doesn't. the three moomentum integral imposes three momentum conservation, but that doesn't impose the energy conservation, so you cannot remove the delta on $E$. Schematically, you have four deltas, three integrate out because you have an integral oover three variables, so you still have one

Comment: Shoot, you are right. I've been doing some digging and I can't seem to find a calculation of $A+B\rightarrow C$ done anywhere. Is is even legitimate to try to calculate the cross section of this reaction? Does the general formula apply to this process? Isn't it just decay in reverse?

Comment: I think it is legitimate, but I haven't been able to find  it done anywhere neither.